# How to set axis' labels in a Line Chart using Apache Poi

Tags: java, excel, charts, apache-poi

I'm trying to automate a report creation using java and Apache POI. I'm almost there, but can't find how to set the axis' labels in a XSSFChart.

I already found how to to set the chart's title(
[Apache POI set Excel chart title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30532612/apache-poi-set-excel-chart-title) ). Maybe there is a similar way to work it around, but I'm no developer and have no idea on how to start.

Can anyone help?

My code up to now:

```
public void grafico(String nomeplanilhadados, String nomeplanilhagrafico, Date datainicial, Date datafinal, String[] nomesmarcos, String titulo){

    if (datainicial.after(datafinal)){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("A data inicial precisa anteceder a data final");
    }
    Sheet dados = this.wb.getSheet(nomeplanilhadados);
    Sheet planilhagrafico = this.wb.getSheet(nomeplanilhagrafico);
    Drawing drawing = planilhagrafico.createDrawingPatriarch();
    ClientAnchor anchor = drawing.createAnchor(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 4, 17, 20);
    Chart chart = drawing.createChart(anchor);
    ChartLegend legend = chart.getOrCreateLegend();
    legend.setPosition(LegendPosition.TOP_RIGHT);
    LineChartData data = chart.getChartDataFactory().createLineChartData();

    // Use a category axis for the bottom axis.
    ChartAxis bottomAxis = chart.getChartAxisFactory().createCategoryAxis(AxisPosition.BOTTOM);
    bottomAxis.setNumberFormat("MMM/yyyy");

    ValueAxis leftAxis = chart.getChartAxisFactory().createValueAxis(AxisPosition.LEFT);
    leftAxis.setCrosses(AxisCrosses.AUTO_ZERO);

    //retrieve the data
    int linhainicial=-1;
    int linhafinal=-1;
    Iterator<Row> rowIterator = dados.iterator();
    while(rowIterator.hasNext()){
        Row row = rowIterator.next();
        Cell cell = row.getCell(0);
        if(cell!=null){
            SimpleDateFormat formatodata = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
            Date date=cell.getDateCellValue();

            if (linhainicial==-1 && date.compareTo(datainicial)>=0){
                linhainicial=cell.getRowIndex();
            }
            if( date.compareTo(datafinal)<=0){
                linhafinal=cell.getRowIndex();
            }
        }
    }

    ChartDataSource<Number> xs = DataSources.fromNumericCellRange(dados, new CellRangeAddress(linhainicial, linhafinal, 0, 0));
    Row primeiralinha = dados.getRow(0);
    Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = primeiralinha.iterator();
    while(cellIterator.hasNext()){
        Cell cell=cellIterator.next();
        if(cell!=null && Arrays.asList(nomesmarcos).contains(cell.getStringCellValue())){
            ChartDataSource<Number> ys1 = DataSources.fromNumericCellRange(dados, new CellRangeAddress(linhainicial, linhafinal, cell.getColumnIndex(), cell.getColumnIndex()));
            //data.addSerie(xs, ys1);
            LineChartSerie chartSerie = data.addSerie(xs, ys1);
            chartSerie.setTitle(cell.getStringCellValue());
        }
    }

    XSSFChart xchart = (XSSFChart) chart;
    CTChart ctChart = xchart.getCTChart();
    CTTitle title = ctChart.addNewTitle();
    CTTx tx = title.addNewTx();
    CTTextBody rich = tx.addNewRich();
    rich.addNewBodyPr();  // body properties must exist, but can be empty
    CTTextParagraph para = rich.addNewP();
    CTRegularTextRun r = para.addNewR();
    r.setT(titulo);




    chart.plot(data, bottomAxis, leftAxis);    

}
```

Answer (score 1):

try use this method.

```
public static void setAxisTitle(XSSFChart chart, int axisIdx, String title) {
    CTValAx valAx = chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getValAxArray(axisIdx);
    CTTitle ctTitle = valAx.addNewTitle();
    ctTitle.addNewLayout();
    ctTitle.addNewOverlay().setVal(false);
    CTTextBody rich = ctTitle.addNewTx().addNewRich();
    rich.addNewBodyPr();
    rich.addNewLstStyle();
    CTTextParagraph p = rich.addNewP();
    p.addNewPPr().addNewDefRPr();
    p.addNewR().setT(title);
    p.addNewEndParaRPr();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you got the answer yet. I'm not sure what your question is.
I'm guessing that you want to set the axis labels so that your x-axis begins from the lowest/highest point. You can use this

```
bottomAxis.setCrosses(AxisCrosses.MIN)
```

or

```
bottomAxis.setCrosses(AxisCrosses.MAX)
```

You already used this in your code:

```
bottomAxis.setCrosses(AxisCrosses.AUTO_ZERO)
```

Answer (score 0):

Александр Кушнир's answer is a good way to add axis title，but the method he gave need some modification.

//set title of category axis

```
public static void setCatAxisTitle(XSSFChart chart, int axisIdx, String title) {
    CTCatAx valAx = chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getCatAxArray(axisIdx);
    CTTitle ctTitle = valAx.addNewTitle();
    ctTitle.addNewLayout();
    ctTitle.addNewOverlay().setVal(false);
    CTTextBody rich = ctTitle.addNewTx().addNewRich();
    rich.addNewBodyPr();
    rich.addNewLstStyle();
    CTTextParagraph p = rich.addNewP();
    p.addNewPPr().addNewDefRPr();
    p.addNewR().setT(title);
    p.addNewEndParaRPr();
}


public static void setValueAxisTitle(XSSFChart chart, int axisIdx, String title) {
    CTValAx valAx = chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getValAxArray(axisIdx);
    CTTitle ctTitle = valAx.addNewTitle();
    ctTitle.addNewLayout();
    ctTitle.addNewOverlay().setVal(false);
    CTTextBody rich = ctTitle.addNewTx().addNewRich();
    rich.addNewBodyPr();
    rich.addNewLstStyle();
    CTTextParagraph p = rich.addNewP();
    p.addNewPPr().addNewDefRPr();
    p.addNewR().setT(title);
    p.addNewEndParaRPr();
}
```

// Use a category axis for the bottom axis.

```
 ChartAxis bottomAxis =chart.getChartAxisFactory().createCategoryAxis(AxisPosition.BOTTOM);
 ValueAxis leftAxis =chart.getChartAxisFactory().createValueAxis(AxisPosition.LEFT);
```

//But I didn't find a good way to get axisIdx.If there is only one chart in the plot area,you can set axis title like this.

```
setValueAxisTitle(xchart,0,"title of bottom axis");
 setCatAxisTitle(xchart,0, "title of left axis");
```

Answer (score 0):

**C# Example**

```
 

//set Value Axis
private static void setValueAxisTitle(XSSFChart chart, int axisIdx, String title)
            {
                NPOI.OpenXmlFormats.Dml.Chart.CT_ValAx valAx = chart.GetCTChart().plotArea.valAx[axisIdx];
                valAx.title = new NPOI.OpenXmlFormats.Dml.Chart.CT_Title();
                NPOI.OpenXmlFormats.Dml.Chart.CT_Title ctTitle = valAx.title;
                ctTitle.layout = new NPOI.OpenXmlFormats.Dml.Chart.CT_Layout();
                ctTitle.overlay = new NPOI.OpenXmlFormats.Dml.Chart.CT_Boolean();
                ctTitle.overlay.val = 1;
                ctTitle.AddNewTx();
    
                NPOI.OpenXmlFormats.Dml.Chart.CT_TextBody rich = ctTitle.tx.AddNewRich();
                rich.AddNewBodyPr();
                rich.AddNewLstStyle();
                rich.AddNewP();
                NPOI.OpenXmlFormats.Dml.CT_TextParagraph p = rich.p[0];
                p.AddNewPPr();
                p.pPr.defRPr = new NPOI.OpenXmlFormats.Dml.CT_TextCharacterProperties();
                p.AddNewR().t=title;
                p.AddNewEndParaRPr();
            }
    
//set cat Axis
private static void setCatAxisTitle(XSSFChart chart, int axisIdx, string title)
            {
                 
                chart.GetCTChart().plotArea.catAx[axisIdx].title = new NPOI.OpenXmlFormats.Dml.Chart.CT_Title();
                NPOI.OpenXmlFormats.Dml.Chart.CT_Title ctTitle = chart.GetCTChart().plotArea.catAx[axisIdx].title;// new NPOI.OpenXmlFormats.Dml.Chart.CT_Title();
                ctTitle.layout = new NPOI.OpenXmlFormats.Dml.Chart.CT_Layout();
                ctTitle.layout.AddNewManualLayout();
                NPOI.OpenXmlFormats.Dml.Chart.CT_Boolean ctbool = new NPOI.OpenXmlFormats.Dml.Chart.CT_Boolean();
                ctbool.val = 1;
                ctTitle.overlay = ctbool;
                ctTitle.AddNewTx();
                NPOI.OpenXmlFormats.Dml.Chart.CT_TextBody rich = ctTitle.tx.AddNewRich();
                rich.AddNewBodyPr();
    
                rich.AddNewLstStyle();
                rich.AddNewP();
                NPOI.OpenXmlFormats.Dml.CT_TextParagraph p = rich.p[0];
                p.AddNewPPr();
                p.AddNewR().t = title;
                p.AddNewEndParaRPr();
                 
            }
```